# Hover effect clipped to parent using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousellite

I am trying to use Bootstrap and my own css to create a hover effect. The issue is that the parent container, the carousel, is clipping my hover effect.

The look I am going for is something like this (hover over items with long descriptions):

http://www.ebay.com/sch/Other-/26261/i.html?rt=nc&_dmd=2

This is what my attempt looks like now:

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I’ve tried overriding the parent overflow elements to no avail.

The hover effect needs to:

- Be the same size for all images in the carousel
- Overwrite any content below it

Here’s the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rboarman/bZ4yD/1/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The overflow on `.carousel-container` is containing it all and there's no way around it without removing it or moving the title element so that it doesn't get clipped.

Comment: Setting that overflow to visible doesn't work

Comment: Seems like the jquery plugin you're using for the carousel is assigning inline styles.

Comment: Yes that is the case. Even if I remove the styles, the content is clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, why not just use a Popover?:

```
$('.thumb-hover').popover({
  title: "This is a title",
  content: "This is a test",
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'bottom'
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mmfansler/Zr3EN/)

Comment: Not a bad idea. I am trying acheive this: http://www.ebay.com/sch/Other-/26261/i.html?rt=nc&_dmd=2

Comment: Oh, I see now. Hmmm... Well, I'm going to leave this answer up, even though it may not be what you're looking for. You should put that link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem easy to play with the overflow since the plugin already uses it.

You can achieve some interesting result by setting both X and Y `overflow` to visible : [demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/bZ4yD/4/)

```css
.carousel-container:hover {
    overflow-y: visible!important;
    overflow-x: visible!important;
}
```

However, the X overflow breaks the plugin style.

But it doesn't work at all on google chrome, so my advice would be not to use this plugin.

---

You would get almost the same problem with another plugin, because [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6421966/1478467)

[Demo with Bootstrap Carousel (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/bZ4yD/6/)

---

Maybe you should think about using some (homemade?) JavaScript, since the carousel requires it anyway.